# In my scrapy spider my parse module is not working, its not printing

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

my parse module is not getting called and it's not printing anything here is my code please if anybody can help me with this then please solve it

```py
class myspider(scrapy.Spider):

    name='myspider'

    def start_requests(self):
        print("h1"+"\n")
        Url="https://www.datacamp.com/courses"
        return scrapy.Request(url=Url ,callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        print("hello")


process = CrawlerProcess()

process.crawl(myspider)

process.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `print()` statements will get eaten by Scrapy.
You should use `self.log("hello")` or, to be more explicit, `self.logger.warning("hello")` in Spider code (and `logging.warning()`after `import logging` outside spider code, such as extensions).

You should also return a list or iterable from `start_requests`:

```py
# list
return [scrapy.Request(url=Url ,callback=self.parse)]
# or generator
yield scrapy.Request(url=Url ,callback=self.parse)
```

(edited: I overlooked the start_requests return before)

Answer (score 1):

Your error here - using return, so it will print out "h1", but not "hello". You should use yield instead, you can use return (but don't) only for the last function in this chain of functions callings, (parse) in this case. But it also better to use yield. Something like this:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class myspider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider'

    def start_requests(self):
        print("h1")
        url = "https://www.datacamp.com/courses"
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        print("hello")
        blabla = set(response.css('.course-block__title::text').getall())
        for bla in blabla:
            print(bla)
            yield {
                'coursename': bla
            }


process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(myspider)
process.start()
```

Also, it nice to show traceback of error, in your case with return instead of yield it shows something like this:

```
h1
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2019-08-04 21:07:11 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2019-08-04 21:07:11 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 184, in crawl
    return self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 188, in _crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1613, in unwindGenerator
    return _cancellableInlineCallbacks(gen)
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1529, in _cancellableInlineCallbacks
    _inlineCallbacks(None, g, status)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 87, in crawl
    start_requests = iter(self.spider.start_requests())
builtins.TypeError: 'Request' object is not iterable

2019-08-04 21:07:11 [twisted] CRITICAL: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 87, in crawl
    start_requests = iter(self.spider.start_requests())
TypeError: 'Request' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Also, don't use print for debugging, install something like PyCharm Community Edition (or vscode) and read or watch the video about debugging instruments there. Search something like "pycharm debugging" on youtube.